# Dependency Injecting the Laravel Cache System

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there anyway to inject the laravel cache system and have access to the increment method.

`\Cache::increment('key');`

So far I have the following, but no increase method.

```
/**
 * @var Cache\Repository
 */
protected $cache;

/**
 * RateLimiter constructor.
 *
 * @param Cache\Repository $cache
 */
public function __construct(Cache\Repository $cache)
{
    $this->cache = $cache;
}
```

I've tried injecting `Cache\Store` but that is not instantiable

EDIT:

`use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache;` is not show in above extract, but it's there.

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades#facade-class-reference) the underline class of the `Cache` facade is `Illuminate\Cache\Repository`, not `Cache\Repository`

Comment: Thats what I'm doing, I didn't show the use statement in the question